# I've got 'export TEZOS_CLIENT_UNSAFE_DISABLE_DISCLAIMER=Y' in my bash profile, why does my tezos disclaimer still show?

Tags: setup

I've got `export TEZOS_CLIENT_UNSAFE_DISABLE_DISCLAIMER=Y` in my bash profile. Why does my tezos disclaimer still show?

Running on Mac Mojave.

My full bash profile rn:

```
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 65536 200000
export TEZOS_CLIENT_UNSAFE_DISABLE_DISCLAIMER=Y
```

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I see sudo in there. Are you running your node with sudo or another user and in which environment did you set TEZOS_CLIENT_UNSAFE_DISABLE_DISCLAIMER?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. For some reason, I am running on Mac and had a .bash-profile and .bash_profile. I edited the wrong one. The sudo is for the increase maxfiles, unrelated to the disclaimer removal.